# Print button background color

Tags: ios, swift3

Hi is there any way to print out selected button background color as string value?? For now when i click button and try to print value it gives be something like this -:

```
Optional(UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.870588 0.721569 0.529412 1)
```

can I get color name somehow?Like Green,Blue?

Answer (score 0):

This what you get here is color space in RGBA format, given:

Red: 0.870588
Green: 0.721569
Blue: 0.529412
Alpha: 1

If you do some math and multiply these numbers by 255, you get:

R: 221,99994
G: 184,000095
B: 135,00006

which looks like this:

https://www.colorcodehex.com/ddb887/

I guess there is no way to the absolute name of color, except you make enum with ranges and setup colors from the ranges... but I think No one is so crazy to do this... so you have to stick with this for now :)